# View at the bottom, moves to the top when clicked

Tags: swift, view, scrollview, action

I have 2 views in my view controller (green and blue). I want the blue view keeps always at the bottom of the page, first. But when i click it, I want the blue view moves to the top. I don’t understand how to make it. Do I need a scrollview behind, with a button action, or other ?

Can anyone help me please ? I tear my hair out for 2 days…

An example of the structure : http://imageshack.com/a/img911/6135/QOF1rl.png

Comment: did you code something ? or did you drag in drop into the **Storyboard**

Comment: All with the Storyboard and some constraints...

Comment: you should try to remove the constraints and run the program to see if the view kept changing..

Answer (score 0):

> when you button tapped remove green view(if not needed). then change the blue view center with an animation.